# View is smaller than the viewcontoller after updating to iPadOS

Tags: xcode, ipad, viewcontroller, ios13, ipados

After updating to Xcode 11 and iPadOS this is how my view looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUUzt.jpg

Before the view was filling the whole screen.

When I switch to iPhone layout the issue disappears, but stays on all iPads.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I verified this began with iOS13. The fix in my case was to change the presentation style of the View Controller from "Automatic" to "Full Screen".

I want to understand better what changed here from 12 to 13, and if this is a proper fix. I'll update with anything else I find.

For context, my View Controller was being presented with a "Show" segue, which is an adaptive segue. So perhaps the adaptivity defaults have changed in iOS13.

[image]

Comment: If you have childviews you have to set the parentview's presentation style.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define some constraints for regular width and regular height using [size classes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/).